# openerp-server some db issues when starting server

Tags: postgresql, odoo

Starting openerp-server in debug mode returns some db error as you can see below. Any thoughts ?

```
[2011-11-21 15:22:03,393] DEBUG:orm:column relate is in the table ir_model_fields but not in the corresponding object ir.model.fields
[2011-11-21 15:22:03,401] DEBUG:orm:column usage is in the table ir_act_url but not in the corresponding object ir.actions.url
[2011-11-21 15:22:03,401] DEBUG:orm:column email_server is in the table ir_act_server but not in the corresponding object ir.actions.server
[2011-11-21 15:22:03,405] DEBUG:orm:column report is in the table ir_act_server but not in the corresponding object ir.actions.server
[2011-11-21 15:22:03,413] DEBUG:orm:column trigger_type is in the table wkf_transition but not in the corresponding object workflow.transition
[2011-11-21 15:22:03,417] DEBUG:orm:column version_pattern is in the table ir_module_module_dependency but not in the corresponding object ir.module.module.dependency
[2011-11-21 15:22:03,421] DEBUG:orm:column x_site is in the table res_partner_address but not in the corresponding object res.partner.address
[2011-11-21 15:22:03,425] DEBUG:orm:column overdue_msg is in the table res_company but not in the corresponding object res.company
[2011-11-21 15:22:03,437] DEBUG:orm:column avg_answers is in the table report_crm_case_section but not in the corresponding object report.crm.case.section
[2011-11-21 15:22:03,437] DEBUG:orm:column perc_done is in the table report_crm_case_section but not in the corresponding object report.crm.case.section
[2011-11-21 15:22:03,437] DEBUG:orm:column perc_cancel is in the table report_crm_case_section but not in the corresponding object report.crm.case.section
[2011-11-21 15:22:03,441] DEBUG:orm:column ics_object_id is in the table document_directory_content but not in the corresponding object document.directory.content
[2011-11-21 15:22:03,441] DEBUG:orm:column ics_domain is in the table document_directory_content but not in the corresponding object document.directory.content
[2011-11-21 15:22:03,445] DEBUG:orm:column code is in the table crm_case but not in the corresponding object crm.case
[2011-11-21 15:22:03,449] DEBUG:orm:column debit_limit is in the table res_partner but not in the corresponding object res.partner
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are not errors; they are only warnings advising columns in tables that are not used in the object models. This can happen following module updates, and signals that eventually those columns could be dropped from the database.